# Submit HTML form using javascript but send it through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to submit a form using `form.submit()` and making the submission go through ajax instead of redirecting the url?

Here's what I have:

```
var form = document.form

form.onsubmit = function() {
  var params = {
    type: "POST",
    url: form.action
  }
  $.ajax(params).then(function(resp) {
     // handle response
  })
}
form.submit()
```

However the submission does not hit the callback and instead redirects the browser to the `form.action` url. How can I avoid the redirection and submit via ajax?

Comment: Why do you need to call `form.submit()` if you want to handle it manually?

Comment: did you try `onsubmit="return false"` ? on form tag properties

Comment: Calling native submit yourself will bypass event listeners

Comment: @Jeto i'm writing an extension and for some reason the site i'm writing it for won't accept it and returns an empty response without hitting form.submit()

Comment: You want to execute ajax request on form action and at the end submit the form too? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call `form.submit()` and execute your code directly:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');

var params = {
  type: 'GET',
  url: form.action
}
$.ajax(params).then(function (resp) {
  console.log('ajax call successful');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1">
</form>
```

If you already have a `form.onsubmit` handler and absolutely need to use it, just call it (looks a bit ugly, but does the job):

```js
var form = document.getElementById('form');

form.onsubmit = function () {
  var params = {
    type: 'GET',
    url: form.action
  }
  $.ajax(params).then(function (resp) {
    console.log('ajax call successful');
  });
};

form.onsubmit();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1">
</form>
```

Note: changed the verbs to `GET` for the purpose of these samples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false at the end of your function.

`return: false`

Otherwise, it will submit the form to the specified URL in the action.

Answer (score 0):

While calling  native `submit()` will bypass event listeners, since you are already using jQuery you could use  jQuery submit listener and prevent it when event is triggered programatically

```
$(form).on('submit',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var params = {
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    url: this.action
  }
  $.ajax(params).then(function(resp) {
     // handle response
  })

// trigger jQuery submit
}).submit()
```